# Filtering a Topojson on server-side. Which part of topology I need?

Tags: d3, topojson

I have a big Topojson which I want to avoid loading it at page load. Instead I would like to parse on server-side at user request, sending back chunks of this original Topojson to be ploted.

So I want to filter by a list of attributes in topojson. Initially I thought that just sending its corresponding geometries with its arcs would be OK (sorry, i am used to GeoJSON) but then I see below the Topology section, which I am afraid is quite dependent on the previously selected arcs (in "Geometry").

Topology section is quite a very long part of this TopoJSON. The question is, as I cannot find a link between the arcs in "Geometry" and "Topology", do I have to load all Topology part, even if I only select a few of "Geometries"? it would not solve my problem at all… any alternative?

I want to filter by COD_POSTAL

```
  "geometries": [
    {
      "type": "Polygon", 
      "properties": {
        "COD_POSTAL": "08630"
      }, 
      "arcs": [
        [
          0, 
          1, 
          2
   ]
]
},
    {
      "type": "Polygon", 
      "properties": {
        "COD_POSTAL": "08256"
      }, 
      "arcs": [
        [
          8, 
          9, 
          10, 
          11, 
          12, 
          13
        ]
      ]
    }
```